# Create Hash from Array of Date objects with Month as Key

Tags: ruby

What is the most efficient way to create a Hash from an Array of Date objects where the month is the key and the value is an Array of dates? Currently, I have the following.

```
require 'date'

...
start, finish = args.start, args.end # Assume this has been implemented
date_map = {}
(start..finish).map do |date|
    unless date_map.has_key? date.month then date_map[date.month] = [date]
    else date_map[date.month] << date end
end
```

Is there a more efficient way to accomplish the aforementioned block of code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)

```
(start..finish).group_by(&:month)
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Just saw @Kyle's answer.  Hard to improve on that.

You can write your code like this:

```
date_map = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }
start.upto(finish) { |date| date_map[date.month] << date }
```

or, more compactly:

```
date_map = start.upto(finish).with_object(Hash.new { |h,k] h[k] = [] }) \
  { |date, h| h[date.month] << date }
```

You'll also see it done this way:

```
date_map = start.upto(finish).with_object({}) { |date, h| 
  (h[date.month] ||= []) << date }
```

Comment: Can you write your first one as `start.upto(finish) { |date| date_map[date.month] << date }` ? [upto](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-upto).